# What is the path for html file, to access it

Tags: rest, web

I created Dynamic Web Project In Eclipse and created some html pages.
I have another Maven Project Of Java REST API. In Maven Project **src->main->webapp->WEB-INF** , I pasted my html, so i want to access this html pages, so what should be the path ?
Please Check Image,

[image: Maven Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Your UI resources should not be under WEB-INF folder. You should place your html and CSS folder directly under webapp. You can then access it by URL **http://localhost:port/InteractDemo/html** (port must be modified as per the server)

Comment: @sunil which server you are using? Also share the access URL. Make sure the server is up on the port.